# Use rspec only in integration tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I have a project which works well with rails default test suite Test::Unit and I have no reason to change the tests I have written. But when I write integration test with capybara, I found that capybara always work with rspec and I have some problem when using capybara with Test::Unit. So i decide to use rspec in Integration Test.

But here is the problem. After running `rails g rspec:install` the cmd `rails g model` will create test in spec, how can i use rspec for only integration test and use Test::Unit in other test.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you installed the `rspec-rails` gem. The gem [configures Rails to use RSpec for testing](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/v2.13.0/lib/rspec-rails.rb). Generator are usually run in development, so by scoping `rspec-rails` to a `:test` [group in your Gemfile](http://gembundler.com/v1.2/groups.html), Rails should not load the gem in development.

```
group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end
```

You could also overwrite the settings set by `rspec-rails` after the gem was loaded.